# How to Get a Widowed Line to Appear on the Previous Page

Tags: widows-orphans

I am currently working on a document with a large font and many short sections. Subsequently, I encounter many "widow lines" --- a single line of text occupying an entire page. Getting a bit tired taking care of these manually, I figured that I would try using the package `nowidow`; but alas, it always (for me anyway), transforms a single line on one page to two single lines on one page. For example,

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 6.75in \textwidth 5.5in
%\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\enlargethispage{0.7\baselineskip}
\LARGE
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

produces the widowed line

[image]

But, when I invoke `\usepackage{nowidow}` in the preamble, I then get two lines off by themselves on a page:

[image]

I would like no such lines. And since my sections are generally short with a title far below the top of the page, there should be plenty of room on such pages to contain the extra errant line.

I could (and do use `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to add a little more space, but this is always on a case-by-case basis. I would like to accomplish this automatically, if possible.

So, my question is: How may I force LaTeX (or rather, the `nowidow` package) to automatically put widowed lines on the previous page instead of the way it usually corrects the problem; that is, instead of always changing one lone single line into two lone single lines? If this cannot be done is there an alternative to the `nowidow` package that will do this?

Comment: You can try `usepackage[defaiultlines=0,all](nowidow}` which seems to do what you wanr but keeps coming up with an error message `Missing \begin{document}` but if you ignore that all seems to be well.

Comment: @Peter Wilson Is that `defaiultlines=0` or `defaultlines=0`?

Comment: @Peter Wilson I've tried what you suggested using `defaultlines=0` and although the widowed line is brought back to the first page, there is no separation between the paragraphs, usepackage[defaultlines=0,all]{nowidow} appears in very small print at the top of the page, and of course, I encountered the error message(s) which you forewarned me about.  Thank you though for offering the suggestion.